# Terraform - DB and security group are in different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, rds, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

### **What am I trying to achive:**

Create and RDS Aurora cluster and place it in the same VPC as EC2 instances that I start so they can comunicate.
I'm trying to start an SG named "RDS_DB_SG" and make it part of the VPC i'm creating in the process.
I also create an SG named "BE_SG" and make it part of the same VPC.
I'm doing this so I can get access between the 2 (RDS and BE server).

### What I did so far:

Created an .tf code and started everything up.

### What I got:

It starts ok if I don't include the RDS cluster inside the RDS SG - The RDS creates it's own VPC.
When I include the RDS in the SG I want for him, The RDS cluster can't start and get's an error.

### Error I got:

**"The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-5a***63c and the EC2 security group is in vpc-0e5391*****273b3d"**

### Workaround for now:

I started the infrastructure without specifing a VPC for the RDS. It created it's own default VPC.
I then created manuall VPC-peering between the VPC that was created for the EC2's and the VPC that was created for the RDS.
But I want them to be in the same VPC so I won't have to create the VPC-peering manuall.

### My .tf code:

```
variable "vpc_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR for the VPC"
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env}_vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "vpc_subnet" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env}_vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "subnet_group" {
  name        = "${var.env}-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids  = ["${aws_subnet.vpc_subnet.id}"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "RDS_DB_SG" {
    name = "${var.env}-rds-sg"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    ingress {
        from_port = 3396
        to_port = 3396
        protocol = "tcp"
        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.BE_SG.id}"]
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "BE_SG" {
    name = "${var.env}_BE_SG"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    ingress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 80
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "BE" {
    ami = "ami-*********************"
    instance_type = "t2.large"
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    key_name = "**********"
    tags = {
        Name = "WEB-${var.env}"
        Porpuse = "Launched by Terraform"
        ENV = "${var.env}"
    }

    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.vpc_subnet.id}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.BE_SG.id}", "${aws_security_group.ssh.id}"]
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds-cluster" {
    cluster_identifier = "${var.env}-cluster"
    database_name = "${var.env}-rds"
    master_username = "${var.env}"
    master_password = "PASSWORD"
    backup_retention_period = 5
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.RDS_DB_SG.id}"]
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "rds-instance" {
    count = 1
    cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.rds-cluster.id}"
    instance_class = "db.r4.large"
    engine_version = "5.7.12"
    engine = "aurora-mysql"
    preferred_backup_window = "04:00-22:00"
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve my first goal?

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to put the EC2 instances and the RDS instance in different VPCs or you're not trying to do that but getting an error that the DB instance and security group are in different VPCs? It would be helpful if you showed the exact error you got as well.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm trying to make the EC2 instances and the RDS to be a part of the same VPC because I want them to be able to communicate in the 172.*.*.* interface. The full error is "The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-5ac6c63c and the EC2 security group is in vpc-0e5391da45a273b3d"

Comment: The EC2 instances were started under the VPC I created int the Terraform.
But the RDS started in his own VPC created automatically.
What I did for now is I manually created a VPC peering between the two VPC's and added a route between them.
I'm creating an "aws_vpc" then I create an "aws_subnet" that connects to the VPC and a "vpc_cidr" that connects to the subnet.
I then create an "aws_security_group" and the EC2 instances are using that SG with no issues.
Can't add the RDS to the same SG. Even tried creating "aws_db_security_group" but then I ran into issues with errors about AZ's.